# How to remove entire row in a table when checkbox unchecked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes on top for categories. When user 'check/select' the category, corresponding list from database will be shown in the table below.

The structure of the table as below:

```
<table id="boxA">
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
        <table>
         <tr>
           <td>List 1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>List 2</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>List 3</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My script as following,

```
<script>
       $("#slider1").change(function() {
       var value = $(this).val();
       sendtobox(value, $("input[type=checkbox]").val());
      });

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {  
     var selectedval = $(this).val();
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var selectedtext = $(this).next().text();
        sendtobox(selectedval, $("#slider1").val());
     }
      else {
        **$("th."+selectedval).remove();**//controls removing from boxA

     }
    });
</script>
```

EDIT : checkbox Markup

```
<ul class="box small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-2">
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Primary]" id="level" class="level" value="1"><label>Primary</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Upper Secondary]" id="level" class="level" value="2"><label>Upper Secondary</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[University]" id="level" class="level" value="3"><label>University</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Lower Secondary]" id="level" class="level" value="4"><label>Lower Secondary</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Pre University]" id="level" class="level" value="5"><label>Pre University</label></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Other]" id="level" class="level" value="6"><label>Other</label></li>                 
              </ul>
```

HTML as per rendered 'inspect element'

```
   <table id="boxA">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <th class="1 title">Primary</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
     </tbody>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

And mine:

```
<?php
$last_category = "";

echo"<table>;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $levels=$row['level_name'];
    $levels_id=$row['level_id'];
    $subjects= $row['subject_name'];
    $subjects_id= $row['subject_id'];
   if($last_category != $levels) {
        $last_category = $levels;

        echo '<tr><th class="' . $q .' title">'. $levels .'</th>';

    }

    echo '<table id="inner"><tr><td>'. $subjects . '</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="sub['.$subjects_id.']" id="sub" value=""></td>';
    echo'<td><input type="textbox" name="rate2['.$subjects_id.']" class="rate2" value="'.$r.'" id="rate2"></td></tr></table>';

    if($last_category != $levels)
        echo '</tr>';
}


echo"</table>";
?>
```

This(  `$("th."+selectedval).remove();`  )is where it controls which element to remove. Currently it just removes the `<th>` for category,the list still showing. How to remove the entire row for the unchecked category please?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the checkbox in your markup?

Comment: Where is the class for ``th`` in your table for that matter?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, teh class for <th> is the checkbox value and the checkbox markup updated above..

Comment: @ShaunakD, updated in edit part

Comment: Do you wish to delete the entire column below `<th>`? Your question says row. Which row?. And your checkboxes have duplicate IDs.

Comment: @sweety you're selecting ``"th."+selectedval`` but ``selectedval`` is ``1`` through ``6`` and the only ``th`` in your table doesn't have a class.

Comment: `$("th."+selectedval).closest('tr').remove();`

Comment: @ShaunakD, I wish to remove the <tr><th></th><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></tr>......

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, my <th> has the checkbox value as class, and my <td> has a class called rate2

Comment: @sweety, the answer below is right. It will work. `closest()` will find the parent `<tr>` and remove everything you wish to.

Comment: do you have control over the html markup? because, if you do, thats the first step in a multipart answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid. The inner table is directly inside the `<tr>` and that is not valid. Only `<td>` and `<th>` elements (or script supporting elements) should be directly inside a `<tr>`. ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element))

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5k8ubet/1/) shows that the inner table does not get removed when the `<tr>` is removed. It also shows that the inner table is not actually inside the outer table (due to the invalid structure of the markup).

Try moving the inner table so it is inside the `<th>`:

```
<table id="boxA">
  <tr>
    <th class="1">Category
        <table>
         <tr>
           <td>List 1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>List 2</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>List 3</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
     </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can then remove the row with:

```
$('th.' + selectedval).closest('tr').remove();
```

---

I think the logic in your PHP is a bit off and won't properly generate the rows. You could try the following:

```
<?php
$last_category = "";

echo "<table>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $levels=$row['level_name'];
    $levels_id=$row['level_id'];
    $subjects=$row['subject_name'];
    $subjects_id=$row['subject_id'];

    // Check if a new row should be started
    if($levels != $last_category) {
        // If this isn't the first row, close the previous row.
        if ($last_category != "") {
            echo '</th></tr>';
        }
        echo '<tr><th class="' . $q . ' title">' . $levels;
        $last_category = $levels;
    }

    echo '<table id="inner"><tr><td>' . $subjects . '</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="sub[' . $subjects_id . ']" id="sub" value=""></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="textbox" name="rate2[' . $subjects_id . ']" class="rate2" value="' . $r . '" id="rate2"></td></tr></table>';
}

// Close the last row.
echo '</th></tr>';
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `$("th."+selectedval).remove();` remove the `th`, and you want to remove the row containing it, then you can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest)/[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent)

```
$("th."+selectedval).closest('tr').remove();
//or just $("th."+selectedval).parent.remove();
```

As noted in the comments, your html is invalid as you have the nested table as a child of a `tr` element, which is invalid.

One possible solution is to use 2 `tr` elements

```
<table id="boxA">
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>List 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>List 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>List 3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then

```
$("th."+selectedval).parent().next().addBack().remove()
```

Comment: if you look at my table structure, after <th> there's no <tr> but <table>. So in your code I changed the  closest('tr') to closest('table')...but it removes the entire table .So when i click other check box also the table not showing.. Then I tried putting id for the inner table  and closest('#inner')...doesnt work either

Comment: Closest searches for parent() and parent element of th,inner table is `<tr>`. So @Arun is right here. `$("th."+selectedval).next('table').remove();` try this then.

Comment: @ShaunakD, your answer makes sense but it doesn't remove at all?

Comment: I think it doesnt remove anything because the nested table structure you are using is invalid. There are no `<thead>,<tbody>` tags. They will be automatically added to your code and the DOM will change. Please use `Inspect Element` in your browser to see the exact structure rendered.

Comment: @ShaunakD you are right... the html is invalid... so the nested table is rendered outside of the parent table - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n5asmg0y/1/

Comment: @sweety you need to fix your html first.... can you update the attached fiddle with a proper html

Comment: One easy solution could be to use 2 trs - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n5asmg0y/2/ - then `$("th."+selectedval).parent().next().addBack().remove()`

Comment: @sweety else use the same script but move the table to the `th` http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n5asmg0y/3/ - but it could alter the display attributes of the second table

Comment: what is there in the second `tr` element... also check what is below the `boxA` table

Comment: @ArunPJohny, as per your fiddle , I placed the second table inside <th> and your script $("th."+selectedval).next('table').remove(); ANd it worked!